# Can I claim damages for identity theft?

Tags: real-estate, theft, fraud

Someone opened a mortgage in my name, fraudulently. Can I stand to benefit from this?

Comment: You mean, presumably, by tracking them down and suing them civilly?

Comment: In general, the best you can do with legal action is restoration, not profit.

Comment: @DaleM - Aren't "treble damages and fees," or "punitive damages" awarded for many civil offenses?

Comment: Only in the US, you didn't give a jurisdiction

Answer (score 1):

There is no upside to having someone "open a mortgage" in your name.

Unless it's your rich uncle who is also paying the mortgage.

The uncle scenario proves the point that any apparent benefit likely amounts to fraud upon any closer inspection.

Comment: I think that this question is more about profiting from court-ordered damages than from the fraudulent act.

Comment: @jimsug Perhaps. In that case I'd venture a guess that the perps are judgment proof.

Comment: What if the original homeowner paid you to do that?